# How do I use XAML to bind a DatagridComboBoxColumn to a ViewModel property that isn't in the DataGrid's ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

### What I'm Attempting

- I have a Datagrid that's bound to a list called FilesToAdd, which is part of my ViewModel.
- I have a Combobox column on that datagrid.
- I would like to bind the ComboBox's selected item to the DocumentType property of the FilesToAdd list item.
- But, I would like to have a list of available choices come from AvailableDocumentTypes, which is a property of the ViewModel itself, not of the FilesToAdd list.

### The XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilesToAdd}" Height="100" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visibility="{Binding FilesAreQueued, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <app:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="File Will be Uploaded As" Binding="{Binding FileDisplayText}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding FileSizeInText}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableDocumentTypes}" Header="Document Type" Visibility="{Binding Data.DocumentTypesAreRequired, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, Source={StaticResource Proxy} }">
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### Update 1: XAML I'm Trying now + DataContext Clarification

Per Kevin's suggestion, I tried:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailableDocumentTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window }}}" Header="Document Type" Visibility="{Binding Data.DocumentTypesAreRequired, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, Source={StaticResource Proxy} }"/>
```

Also tried:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AvailableDocumentTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window }}}" Header="Document Type" Visibility="{Binding Data.DocumentTypesAreRequired, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, Source={StaticResource Proxy} }"/>
```

But I receive the error that it can't be found.

FYI, My DataContext is set in the following way:

In the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="VEUploader.WPF.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:VEUploader.WPF" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding WindowTitle}" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        DataContext="{StaticResource UploaderViewModel}"
        AllowDrop="True"
   >
```

In the code (so I can do dependency injection):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var uploaderViewModel = new UploaderViewModel(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IVEDocumentService>(), ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IArgumentSettingsRetriever>(), ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IVEBudgetService>());
    Resources["UploaderViewModel"] = uploaderViewModel;


    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: How did you bind the Document Type Property from FilesToAdd list? Or is this done automatically in the solution provided by Kevin DiTraglia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a compiler in front of me, but I believe the syntax would look something like this:

```
{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type MyParentControl}}}
```

EDIT: Actually doing some testing of my own, for some reason the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` somehow cannot find the item source, but if you template your own combo box column, it works just fine.  Not sure why that is, but this may be an acceptable work around.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilesToAdd}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Document Type">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                                ItemsSource=
                                "{Binding DataContext.AvailableDocumentTypes, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window }}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This seems to be definitely on the right track. Follow-up: What if the relative source is the data context for the window? My ViewModel is mapped as the datacontext of the window, so I'm not sure if that could be referenced directly..

Comment: @SeanKilleen Sure it can, just replace `MyParentControl` with `Window`

Comment: @SeanKilleen I looked into it a little more and added an edit, I think you need the `DataContext.` to get to the viewmodel.

Comment: Interesting. Makes perfect sense. However, I'm still getting an error that it can't find the binding. Is it because it's defaulting to Level=1? I may have to increase the levels and see how that works out.

Comment: Unless you have more than 1 window in your code (which is doubtful) that shouldn't matter.  Does adding `Path=` help, again it's been a while since I've done this and don't have a compiler in front of me.

Comment: See update 1: I think we're really close but it may have to do with how I'm binding the DataContext in the window element? Update 1 shos how I'm declaring that and the code for the window load.

Comment: @SeanKilleen Can you update what you tried, what you have posted there doesn't seem to correspond with your question.

Comment: Sorry bad copy/paste. Updated.

Comment: @SeanKilleen Actually I changed my ListBox in my example to a datagrid and it's not working for me anymore, let me see if I can figure out what is going on.

Comment: @SeanKilleen I made an edit that got it to work, basically if you template your own combobox data column, it works.  As of now I am not sure why (hooray wpf!)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35091/discussion-between-sean-killeen-and-kevin-ditraglia)